# Tracking system using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

**Background:**
I have a 3rd party application I am building for a company.
I'm building a bot which supplies automated actions using the companies API.
I only have **one** server, the application, the tracking system, the database, and the admin panel all sit on the same server and this must stay.

**How do I track:**
Whenever a user visits one of my landing pages, I immediately save all his info in MySQL table called `visits`. Those params include the get params `($_GET)` with, with an auto generated transaction id (random) alongside some other server params `($_SERVER)` such as the user ip, browser, which landing page he landed etc.
This information is also being saved on his cookies in case he comes back.

When a user actually signs up I save the transaction id I generated on the visit alongside his sign up information in another table called `users`. And that's how I can reach his visit information.

**What is my problem:**
I am using AdWords to send traffic to my landing pages, and when I increase the traffic to stage where I get around 3 visits per second, my server is overloaded and performance drops.

**What can I do to optimize?**

Comment: Why don't you let Google Analytics track all your traffic? You can push custom variables to Google Analytics (for the and you can track conversions.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst How can I use Google Analytics to get for example the get params of a user who signed up? 
In general how can I connect between user who signed up to his unique visit?
Also remember that I need this information LIVE because a user can sign up with his first visit.

Comment: Place a conversion script after signup. GA know the visitor and will connect the conversion to the right visitor. So you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst I'm gonna read their API see if it is possible, reliable and live.

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst Unfortunately the real time reporting does not include the information I need.

Comment: Did you look at the GAPI (Google Analytics API for php)? The benefit of let Google track your visitors is that database intensive operations are done elsewhere

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst yes I did,it seems like most operations there are not live as I need them to be.